# Which Loss function to choose for Sequence Classification Problem?

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

My Problem is as below :
Input : [Sequence of Characters]

Output : [ Sequence of Characters]

Both Input and Output are BOW Representations.

E.g X=[12,3,4,5,6] ---> Y= [1,4,5,7,8]

I am planning to use Keras LSTM for above task.

What should be my Loss Function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most standard way is to model the output distribution using softmax, the appropriate loss function is categorical cross-entropy.

Standard categorial cross-entropy expects the targets as one-hot vectors. If you want to use the indices in `Y` directly, use sparse categorical cross-entropy.

(See example two in [this tutorial](https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-use-keras-sparse_categorical_crossentropy/) it seems to do exactly what you want.)